# Counting number of times value/string occures in field using ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

How do I count the number of times a value/string etc. occures in a field (using field calculator)?

In my example I want to count the number of times the letter "H" occures in a field; see attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [String count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

> str.count(sub[, start[, end]]) Return the number of non-overlapping
>   occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional
>   arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

Example in Field Calculator with Python Parser:

```
tmp =

!BRUKSENHET!.Count('H')
```